# php form working on one server but not working on another server

Tags: php, forms

The basic validations on the form are not even getting triggered!

I've been staring and comparing the code on the new server to the code on the other server, and i know the code is identical ... and maybe there's directory trouble in trying to get to `contactInformationGoogle.php` form, but for now, that's not even my concern. My concern is that why even the basic validations, ie, when form is blank, is not triggering the usual warnings of `* First name is required`, etc???

The exact same form on the other server works! Seriously tearing my hair out ... please help!

This is the form *without* the google's recaptcha widget ... trying to keep it simple for now ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <title>Hotel</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .error {
      color:red;
    }
    body {
      padding-top: 146px;
      padding-top:175px;
    }
    .language_choice_english {
      padding-right: 1%
    }

    .language_choice_japanese {
        padding-right: 3%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
session_start(); //allows use of session variables

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !empty($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token']) {

  $token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;


   if (empty($_POST["first-name"])) {
     $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
   } else {
     $first_name = test_input($_POST["first-name"]);
   }

    if (empty($_POST["last-name"])) {
     $lastNameErr = "Last name is required";
   } else {
     $last_name = test_input($_POST["last-name"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
     $messageErr = "Message is required";
   } else {
     $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
   }


   if(isset($first_name) && isset($last_name) && isset($email) && isset($message))
   {
     $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
     $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
     $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
     $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
     include dirname(__FILE__)."/../../contactInformation.php";
     exit; 
   }
}

else {
  $token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <a class="brand pull-left" href="index.html">
            <img id="Logo" src="./images/logo_72H.gif" alt="Hotel">
            </a>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><span id="overall_title">Daimaru Hotel</span><small id="description_of_city">Little Tokyo, Los Angeles, Downtown</small></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="rooms.html">Rooms & information</a></li>
        <li><a href="reserve.php">Book to Reserve</a></li>
        <li><a href="location.html">Location Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="additional.html">Additional Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <p class="pull-right language_choice_english"><a href="contact.php">English</a></p>
        <p class="pull-right language_choice_japanese"><a href="contact-ja.php"><span lang="ja">日本語</span></a></p>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div id="main-container" class="col-xs-12">

  <div>
    <label>* Required fields</label>
  </div>

  <form class="form-horizontal"  method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">* First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="first-name" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($first_name)) { echo $first_name; }?>">
       <?php if(isset($firstNameErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $firstNameErr . '</span>'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="last-name" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($last_name)) { echo $last_name; }?>">
       <?php if(isset($lastNameErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $lastNameErr . '</span>'); ?>
     </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="<?php if(isset($email)) { echo $email; }?>">
       <?php if(isset($emailErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $emailErr . '</span>'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Message</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Please type in your message" name="message" id="message" value="<?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; }?>"></textarea>
       <?php if(isset($messageErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $messageErr . '</span>'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


</div>


 <footer class="col-xs-12 roomsFooter">  

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">2015 Hotel -- All rights reserved</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Terms of Use</div>
       <div class="col-md-4">Facebook / Twitter / Instagram </div>
    </div>  
  </footer>

  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <title>Hotel</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <style type="text/css">
    .error {
      color:red;
    }
    body {
      padding-top: 146px;
      padding-top:175px;
    }
    .language_choice_english {
      padding-right: 1%
    }

    .language_choice_japanese {
        padding-right: 3%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
session_start(); //allows use of session variables

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !empty($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token']) {

  $token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;


   if (empty($_POST["first-name"])) {
     $firstNameErr = "First name is required";
   } else {
     $first_name = test_input($_POST["first-name"]);
   }

    if (empty($_POST["last-name"])) {
     $lastNameErr = "Last name is required";
   } else {
     $last_name = test_input($_POST["last-name"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   }

   if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
     $messageErr = "Message is required";
   } else {
     $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
   }


   if(isset($first_name) && isset($last_name) && isset($email) && isset($message))
   {
     $_SESSION['first_name'] = $first_name;
     $_SESSION['last_name'] = $last_name;
     $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
     $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
     include dirname(__FILE__)."contactInformation.php";
     exit; 
   }
}

else {
  $token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
  $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}
?>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <a class="brand pull-left" href="index.html">
            <img id="DaimaruLogo" src="./images/logo_72H.gif" alt="New Daimaru Hotel">
            </a>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><span id="overall_title">Daimaru Hotel</span><small id="description_of_city">Little Tokyo, Los Angeles, Downtown</small></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="rooms.html">Rooms & information</a></li>
        <li><a href="reserve.php">Book to Reserve</a></li>
        <li><a href="location.html">Location Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="additional.html">Additional Info</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <p class="pull-right language_choice_english"><a href="contact.php">English</a></p>
        <p class="pull-right language_choice_japanese"><a href="contact-ja.php"><span lang="ja">日本語</span></a></p>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
<div id="main-container" class="col-xs-12">

  <div>
    <label>* Required fields</label>
  </div>

  <form class="form-horizontal"  method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

  <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" />
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">* First Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="first-name" id="first-name" placeholder="First Name" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($first_name)) { echo $first_name; }?>">
       <?php if(isset($firstNameErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $firstNameErr . '</span>'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Last Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="last-name" id="last-name" placeholder="Last Name" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($last_name)) { echo $last_name; }?>">
       <?php if(isset($lastNameErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $lastNameErr . '</span>'); ?>
     </div>
    </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Email</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" type="email" value="<?php if(isset($email)) { echo $email; }?>">
       <?php if(isset($emailErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $emailErr . '</span>'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">* Message</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Please type in your message" name="message" id="message" value="<?php if(isset($message)) { echo $message; }?>"></textarea>
       <?php if(isset($messageErr)) print ('<span class="error">* ' . $messageErr . '</span>'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>


</div>


 <footer class="col-xs-12 roomsFooter">  

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">2015 Hotel -- All rights reserved</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Terms of Use</div>
       <div class="col-md-4">Facebook / Twitter / Instagram </div>
    </div>  
  </footer>

  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And the `ContactInformation.php`

```
   <?php

    session_start();

    $first_name = $_SESSION['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_SESSION['last_name'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $message = nl2br($_SESSION['message']);

    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output

    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = '';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = '';                 // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '';                           // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 587; 

    $mail->addReplyTo( $email, $first_name );
    $mail->addAddress( $email, $first_name );
    $mail->addAddress( '', 'Staff' );
    $mail->From = '';
    $mail->FromName = 'Staff';


    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

    $mail->Subject = 'Hotel Contact';

    $mail->Body = "<table width='600'><tr><td colspan='2' height='20'><p style='text-align:center; font-size:20px; color:#ddd; padding:0px; margin:0px;'>Copy of Your Contact Form</p></td></tr>"
                  ."<tr><td colspan='2'  height='80' width='600'><p style='color:#d1502d;font-size:50px;text-align:center;padding:0px; margin:0px;'>Hotel</p></td></tr>"
                                ."<tr><td colspan='2'  height='60' width='600' style='text-align:center; color:#606060;font-size:20px;padding:0px; margin:0px;'>Address</td></tr>"
                                ."<tr><td colspan='2'  height='30' width='600' style='text-align:center;'><h3 style='color:#d1502d; '>Tag line</h3></td></tr>"
                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your First Name: </p></td><td height='20' width='300'> <p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px;'>$first_name</p></td></tr>"
                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your Last Name: </p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px;'>$last_name</p></td></tr>"
                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your Email Address: </p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px;'>$email</p></td></tr>"
                                ."<tr><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:10px; margin:0px; text-align:right;'>Your Message:</p></td><td height='20' width='300'><p style='font-size:20px; color:gray; padding:0px; margin:10px;'> $message</p></td></tr></table>"
                                ."<tr><td colspan='2'  height='15' width='600'><p style=' text-align:center;padding:0px; margin:0px;'><a style='color:#d1502d;font-size:15px;text-align:center;padding:0px; margin:0px;text-decoration:none;'href=''>Visit Our Site</a></p></td></tr>";



    $mail->AltBody = 'To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        header('location: url_of_contactError.html');

    } else {
        header('location: url_of_contactResult.html');

    }
```

**EDIT TWO**

Just tried this right now - some basic code with self-php validation: (it worked!!!!)

```
<!-- Coloring error messages -->
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;} 
</style>

<?php
$nameErr = $emailErr = "";
$name = $email = "";
// Define Variables as Empty Values

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
$nameErr = "Name is required";
}else {
$name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
$emailErr = "Email is required";
}else {
$email = test_input($_POST["email"]);

// check if e-mail address is well-formed
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
$emailErr = "Invalid email format"; 
}
}
}

function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>

<p><span class = "error">* required field.</span></p>

<form method = "POST" action = "<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<table>

<tr><td>Name:</td>
<td><input type = "text" name = "name">
<span class = "error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
</td></tr>

<tr><td>E-mail: </td>
<td><input type = "text" name = "email"><span class = "error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span></td></tr>

<tr><td><input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit"> 
</td></tr>

</table>
</form>

<?php
echo ("<p>name is $name</p>");
echo ("<p>email address is $email</p>");
?>
```

Comment: Have you looked at the error logs on the server where this is not working?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, don't have access to the error logs. not possible.

Comment: You probably do if you FTP into your host and look for it. Its normally there somewhere

Comment: I'm not seeing `contactInformationGoogle.php` anywhere in your script (as mentioned in your write-up). I see `contactInformation.php`, however. Is this expected?

Comment: And are the 2 servers running the same version of PHP? To check you can create a file (call it phpinfo.php), and in it put only the following: `<?php phpinfo();` then run it in the browser. Not that I see anything that wouldn't work from one version to the next, but just curious.

Comment: @Marcus, good catch regarding `contactInformationGoogle.php` vs `contactInformation.php` ... there's no difference between the two except for Google's Recaptcha stuff ... anyway, honestly, that's not the issue. I did run `phpinfo` earlier on this server because I was so baffled why it wasn't working ... don't remember what it was. Will post it tomorrow as I don't have access to it now. And yeah, it probably doesn't make any difference ... though I wish it did! Then it would be solved!

Comment: @Marcus, my server is running `PHP Version 5.3.29`, and the other server (the one that's problematic) is running `PHP Version 5.4.19` ... I'm really going crazy here ... I've even transferred older set of files that didn't have google recaptca enabled, and even with them, the validations in the page didn't get triggered at all. What on earth can prevent basic php form validations from working?

Comment: Just to take a step back here... when you submit the (empty) form the page *does* reload, correct? You just receive none of your error messages? But everything else is seemingly working, ie. no errors printed to screen? Would be nice if you had access to your logs :/ And the script there is *exactly* what you're using? It's not part of a larger script or anything?

Comment: @Marcus, I've edited the post above. This is the earlier version that worked on my server and yes, it is exactly as it is. I also put `contactInformation.php` infomation as well. It's almost exactly as is. Obviously I had to strip out info. Oh, just realized that I changed one line in my script right now. I changed this line: ` include dirname(__FILE__)."/../../contactInformation.php";` to this line: ` include dirname(__FILE__)."contactInformation.php";`. I put the file in the same directory because I was so puzzled why it wasn't working on the newer server ... anyway.

Comment: @Marcus As for the page reloading, not sure if it does, but the session token # changes, so, yes, it apparently reloads. Any other questions? Thank you for taking the time to look through all this.

Comment: @Marcus, I'm assuming that it doesn't matter whether it can access `contactInformation.php` right now or not because the basic self php validations are not dependent on accessing that file. What is preventing the basic self validations is what I'm so puzzled about.

Comment: OK, just checking. Just a thought: is there any chance your *other* server, but more importantly the domain you're working on, is an *add-on domain*? E.g. server is registered under *example.com* but you're working in the domain *example.ca*? It could be a cookies issues. In which case, try my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Try running the following code on its own, exactly as provided below. This will test whether sessions are setup properly (and working). Run that in the browser, refresh the page a couple of times, and if `$_SESSION['token']` is `echo`'d to the screen (after a refresh or 2), you'll know that sessions are running as expected.

```
<?php
// session_test.php
session_start();

if ( ! empty($_SESSION['token']) )
    echo 'Session: ' . $_SESSION['token'];
else
    echo 'Session not set.';

$token = uniqid(mt_rand(), true);
$_SESSION['token'] = $token;
```

**ORIGINAL POST**

Just above `session_start();`, try adding the following:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com'); // <--- add this line
session_start();
... rest of code
```

Where `.example.com` is the exact domain name you're accessing (so make sure to change it out, obviously; and keep the preceding `.` to cover the entire server)

Comment: hey, correct me if I'm wrong ... but doesn't `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` not need to access `contactInformation.php` file? Just tried your solution right now though ... and it didn't work! =( Any other ideas what what the problem could be? I just thought of something ... the problematic server is private, ie, locked from the public access. I didn't think to mention it because I didn't think it would affect basic `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>` validation, you know?

Comment: Is there something I'm misunderstanding about the basic validations that's embedded in the page in the code above? I keep thinking that there's something I'm missing ... but what I don't know. Usually I know what the problem is, even if I'm not able to always solve it. But there, I can't even figure out what's preventing basic, basic, basic validations from being triggered!

Comment: hey, I've put in an `edit two` above. Some random basic php-self validation code ... and it works on this server ... I'm beginning to think that it has to do with access problem of `contactInformation.php`, ie, the session stuff that it needs to access? Could it be that?

Comment: I'm curious that the session's aren't sticking (storing), which is causing `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && !empty($_SESSION['token']) && $_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token']) {` to fail every time. Can you add a very, very simple script to test this out? See my edit above...

Comment: hey thank you. i have to try it tomorrow as my access is only on premises, and i have to leave. but will udpate you tomorrow! thank you for your patience! happy thursday!

Comment: hey, fyi, tried the script as you posted in the edit ... it works. hm. i'm thinking that maybe i should completely rewrite this script? Though emy PHP is awful! Can I ask your opinion of this script? It's meant for a commercial purpose, and it doesn't need to go through a database fortunately. But is this script secure? Or is there  something I could do to make it better?

Comment: by the way, if you don't want to post your opinion on the script, that's fine